# SpringBoot -deploying jar in other environments

Tags: spring-boot

I have been able to successfully develop a restful web service on my local machine.  Planning to deploy in production like environment. Below are my 2 questions.

1. I want to deploy into the production like environment. How do I automate so the code connects to production database without any change to application properties file? Currently its hard coded spring.datasource.url
2. How to keep the jar file running in production without termination?

Answer (score 1):

To your first question:
I'm assuming you have your datasource url defined in an "application.properties" (or .yml) inside your jar. If so you can override that utilizing the [externalized configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config) mechanism. That means either putting a application.properties file next to your jar-file or via command line arguments, environment variables or one of the other ways described in the manual.

To your second question:
The spring-boot-maven plugin lets you build executable jars which can be installed as a service on linux systems. Gradle lets you do the same. Please refer to the [deployment section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-install) in the spring boot documentation. Alternatively there are many ways to run a task in the background on linux. I will not cover these since it was done extensively here on the site already.